# Where are sports events announced in the US?

Tags: nba, collegiate

*Note: I was torn between asking this question in SE.Travel or here but I feel it will be better answered by "locals", rather than "travellers". Please let me know if this is an incorrect assumption.*

I will be on vacation in the US (California and Nevada) late April / early May. One of the things I wanted to show my children is the specific atmosphere in US stadiums. I chose basketball as this is a sport we can refer to in France.

I am not particularly interested in a match with star teams (which will be not only difficult to get in, but also sitting in the top row of a 40,000 places stadium is not that exciting) - rather in something typical such as a college match.

**My question: is there a typical place such games are announced, per city?**

In France for instance that would be the web site of the city council (*mairie*). I was also considering Ticketmaster, but it seems to carry only the top games.

Comment: It's worth noting that basketball is almost exclusively a winter sport in the US, and as such the season is pretty much done. The women's college season is done, the men's college season finishes tonight (8th April) and the NBA is into the playoffs which rules out cheap tickets. The exception is the WNBA, but that only starts on 9th May so could be too late for you...

Answer (score 2):

First off most US pro basketball arenas are only seat around 18K or so. At this time, April/May, the NBA regular season is over and the only games will be playoff games which will be expensive. After tonight (April 8, 2019) the NCAA basketball season will be finished as well. As Phillip Kendall mentions in a comment, the WNBA season hasn't started yet.

If you aren't interested in baseball, there is another summer sport in the US your kids are likely familiar with, soccer (football)! The MLS season has just started here.

Now, as your question about where schedules are announced.

The schedules are under the control of individual sporting leagues as they are private enterprises. The league will announce the schedule and individual teams will also announce them. So for the NBA, you can visit NBA.com to see their schedule. Any major newspaper or sports website (like ESPN.com) will have the assorted league schedules as well.

As for tickets, generally, Ticketmaster is the primary ticket sellers for most top leagues, except for baseball which uses Tickets.com. There are also secondary resellers, Stubhub being the most popular.